# How to use sbt plugin as a library dependency in a sbt project?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, multi-project, sbt-plugin

I have an sbt plugin project that uses multi-project build. I would like to use this plugin as a dependency for the other sbt project. I have created a plugin but when I add this plugin to project, I can't seem to get the dependencies to link up correctly.

## sbt-plugin

#### build.sbt

```
name := "sbt-plugin"
  sbtPlugin := true
  val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7", 
  javacOptions := Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8"), 
  scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.8", "-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8"))

  lazy val plugin = (project in file("plugin"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
      name := "plugin"
  )

  lazy val root = (project in file("."))
                .settings(commonSettings: _*)
                .dependsOn(plugin)
                .aggregate(plugin)
```

#### sbt-plugin\plugin\src\main\scala\com\example\Hello.scala

```
  package com.example

  // Sample code I would like to access from another sbt project
  object Hello {
     def show = println("Hello, world!")
  }
```

## plugin-test

plugin-test is an sbt project which i used to test sbt-plugin

#### plugin-test\build.sbt

```
  name := """plugin-test"""

  version := "1.0"

  scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

  libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"

  fork in run := true
```

#### plugin-test\project\plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.example" % "sbt-plugin" % "1.0", "0.13","2.11")
```

#### plugin-test\src\main\scala\com\exam\Test.scala

```
  package com.exam

  object Test {
     def result = com.example.Hello.show()
  }
```

But when i compile plugin-test project it shows following errors:

```
  [error] E:\Play\SBT Plugin\sbt demo1\plugin-test\src\main\scala\com\exam\Test.scala:4: object example is not a member of package com
  [error] def result = com.example.Hello.show()
  [error] one error found
```

I performed publish-local and plugin/publish-local on both projects and the artifacts resolve correctly.
I added sbt-plugin to `plugins.sbt` and compiled the project but `Test.scala` fails to compile with the above error, as if the dependency isn't there.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify your plugin as `addSbtPlugin`, you're adding it only to the build environment (i.e. doing things in `build.sbt`) and not in the classpath of your app (things under `src/main/...`).

In your case you need to use it as a regular dependency.